# Is there a way to know what Ubuntu kernel used iwlwifi-firmware-7260-16.ucode?

Tags: kernel

Is there a way to know what Ubuntu kernel used `iwlwifi-firmware-7260-16.ucode`? I would like to downgrade my kernel because I think I lost bluetooth support since I use -17...

Comment: Ehm If chili555 happens to correct me please accept his ideas but I would believe `iwlwifi-firmware-7260-16.ucode` is for wifi. `ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq` would be bluetoith.

Comment: apparently this is the same intel chip that manage bluetooth and wifi on this motherboard

Comment: I guess that firmware is independent of the kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I did some changes in the order things load in rc and bluetooth came back without anychange to drivers or kernel. Weird! I did not understood what happened but it now works